# Failure initializing default system SSL context - Android Studio

Tags: java, ubuntu, android-studio

I've got problem with Android Studio. When I try to build my project I get an error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestCompile'.
>
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication:app:unspecified
>
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>
> Failure initializing default system SSL context
>   Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit

My configuration: Ubuntu 15.4, Oracle Java 8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, installing the las JDK and setting de environment variables JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92 (wich is the installation path of the last JDK) and changing the JDK segment of PATH solved the problem

Also in **Android Studio** go to **File** then **Project Structure** and in **SDK Location** update the path as well.